# How to find integral's upper limit using optimize function without knowing the interval where it will occur

Tags: r, integral

I'm working on the following to get the upper limit of my integration, as I know I need to have some idea where the point might occur **but in real it can be any value between 0 and infinity**. May I know is there any improvement can be done so that it can work **within 0 and infinity**?

```
findx = function(f, interval, target) {
  optimize(function(x) {
    abs(integrate(f, 0, x)$value-target)
  }, interval)$minimum
}

pdf = function(x, a=2, b=0.5, lam=-1.2, del=1.5){
  s = besselK(2*sqrt(a*b), lam/del, expon.scaled = FALSE)
  pdf = del/2 * (a/b)^(lam/(2*del)) / s * x^(lam-1)*exp(-a*x^del-b*x^(-del))
  return(pdf)
} 

findx(pdf, interval=c(0,Inf), target=runif(1, min = 0, max = 1))
```

The following is the error I get when I have my interval=c(0, Inf)

```
> findx(pdf, interval=c(0,Inf), target=runif(1, min = 0, max = 1))
Error in optimize(function(x) { : invalid 'xmax' value
```

**EDIT:**

Actually, I'm referring to technique in the link of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326736/how-to-find-upper-limit-of-integral-if-area-is-known-in-r but it mentioned that "optimize needs an interval in which to search for a solution so you'll want to have some idea of where the point might occur" but my x is from 0 to infinity in which I wouldn't know where will it occur. While I need to find the minimum upper limit for my integration.

Comment: I would help if you wrote the mathematical equation out, rather than having us reverse-engineer it from the R code...

Comment: I'm looking for the x value for $F(x) = \int_0^x f(x) dx$ in which $0<= x<\infty  $ where I integrated my pdf of $f(x)={(\delta/2)(a/b)^{\lambda/2\delta}}(1/K_{_{\lambda/\delta}}(2\sqrt{ab}))x^{\lambda-1}e^{-at^{\delta}-bt^{-\delta}}$ in order to get my cdf.

Comment: Given that your variable in the density is $x$, how does $t$ come into your pdf? Is it a parameter?

Comment: They are the same, x = t, sorry for my mistake. $f(x)={(\delta/2)(a/b)^{\lambda/2\delta}}(1/K_{_{\lambda/\delta}}(2\sqrt{ab}))x^{\lambda-1}e^{-ax^{\delta}-bx^{-\delta}}$

Comment: So title should be derive cdf from pdf. CDF upper limit is 1 for any distribution, I think so.

Comment: a_statistician, the maximum value for cdf is 1 but I'm looking for the x value within 0<= cdf <= 1 where my x is in the range of 0<= x < $\infty$

Comment: It's not clear what that last comment means.  $0 \leq \text{cdf} \leq 1$ for all values of $x$.  Are you trying to calculate the value of the CDF for a specified value of $x$?  Are you trying to find the value of $x$ that corresponds to a specified value of the CDF?

Comment: More clear: From the title "How to find cdf upper limit", my first response is: Do not need to find, it is 1.

Comment: jbowman, I'm trying to find the x values (the upper limits) by randomly assigning the my target value through runif(1, min = 0, max = 1) where the distance between the value for the integral of my pdf (which is the cdf) and my target value is minimum.

Comment: a_statistician, I think you are confused by my title and I have amended it. Probably you may go through my statement and programming in which I'm getting an error in the part of interval=c(0,Inf). My main concern here is my x should be in between 0 and infinity but I couldn't assign it in my programming. Please note that I have no problem if assigned a value such as interval=c(0,5) where I will get an output of 0.3583414.

Comment: Is it possible you are trying to compute the inverse cumulative function of a [Generalized Inverse Gaussian distribution?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse_Gaussian_distribution)  If so, [there's an `R` package](http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/rmutil/html/GInvGauss.html).  If not, you will need to clarify your objectives.

Comment: Hi Whuber, actually I'm referring to technique in the link of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326736/how-to-find-upper-limit-of-integral-if-area-is-known-in-r but it mentioned that "optimize needs an interval in which to search for a solution so you'll want to have some idea of where the point might occur" but my x is from 0 to infinity in which I wouldn't know where will it occur.